Combine IF with FILTER and QUERY
Workbook "Restriction Reminders" (see example sheet) has two target users:

Admin users who use checkboxes in the restriction_roster tab to
indicate which students have cell phone and/or hallway
restriction.
Staff users, who look up their (staff's) name under the
staff_schedule tab, and quikly glance at which students in each of
their classes have a restriction.

The formula =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,QUERY(FILTER(class_roster!$G:$M, class_roster!$H:$H = $A2, class_roster!$G:$G = "A-1", (class_roster!$M:$M = TRUE)+(class_roster!$N:$N = TRUE)), "select Col6")) currently lists in Column B of staff_schedule all students with restrictions, organized by teacher and meeting day.

While the formula currently gathers the relevant list of students who have either (or both) cell phone or hallway restrictions and matches them with a relevant teacher and meeting day, I want to add the specific restriction type to the list produced in staff_schedule (i.e. parentheses displaying (CELL) or (HALL) or (CELL, HALL)).
That is, for the example sheet, I would like for the result to read:

I have tried adding an IF before TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), but the result is a note for the student regardless of which restriction is chosen, and the last element in a multi-student list didn't list the restriction. Solutions will be well received.

Been a while since I tackled GS, but let's see if I can remember. Request sent. (I will use a different sheet, but you should make a copy of the workbook as well, just in case).

I appreciate the support! Would you be able to make a copy of the document to test things out, so that I can leave the example as is for the integrity of this post?

Well you can just duplicate the sheet and make the columns only editable by you on the original one. Then I can duplicate your duplicate. Unfortunately downloading as excle did not preserve the functions since Excel doesn't have one (the one I mostly use) and I don't think I can copy all of your formulas in a brand new one and it seems a bit excessive for a proof-of-concept when you can make backups or duplicate the sheet multiple times and lock the originals so that we can't edit them. Or make a separate xls that is for view-purposes and post both links: one editable, one not.

You can use
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTER(IF(class_roster!M:N,class_roster!L:L&" ("&class_roster!M$1:N$1&")",),class_roster!H:H=A2))


This is very close to what I'm trying to accomplish, but as is the formula adds two entries for the same student (each entry reflecting hall or cell restriction). Is there a way to combine both restrictions in the same entry (e.g. "John Lennon (cell phone restriction, hallway restriction)", instead of "John Lennon (hallway restriction) and John Lennon (cell phone restriction)?

Try this formula in cell B2:
=JOIN(CHAR(10),ArrayFormula(QUERY({FILTER(class_roster!L:L,class_roster!H:H=$A2,class_roster!G:G="A-1") & " ("&BYROW(IF(FILTER(class_roster!M:N,class_roster!H:H=A2,class_roster!G:G="A-1"),{"CELL","HALL"},),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(",",1,x)))&")"},"where not Col1 contains '()'")))
